# Java exception java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Tags: java, jsoup

I have the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection connection = Jsoup.connect("http://prospective.bryantschools.org/");
    connection.timeout(5000); 

    Document doc;
    try {


        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://prospective.bryantschools.org/").get();

        // get page title
        String title = doc.title();
        System.out.println("title : " + title);

        // get all links
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {

            // get the value from href attribute
            System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
            System.out.println("text : " + link.text());

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And I am getting the following errors

```
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1168)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:512)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
at com.example.kaleb.testjsoup.HTMLParserExample1.main(HTMLParserExample1.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

I've looked around and many people have mentioned that it might because the server's firewall is blocking my request. Is there is any other reason why I'd be getting these exceptions? Is there something I'm doing in my code that is casuing these exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

Try `Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();`. Our web server blocked it because it didn't have a user agent and blocks non-real-person-looking requests.

Comment: So apparently it was the guest wifi that i was using that was blocking my traffic. I'm now on a different wifi and my program runs without exception. I tested the code that you gave me and it does work on the guest wif